# If-iteration based on averages Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find how to do an if-iteration in Excel. I have 5 products, let's say bread, milk, butter, eggs and chocolate. The average flow time of these products should be equal or lower to 21, being maximized for each of the products. In the beginning of the iteration, I order 33 pallets of each product (Column T).  For 33 pallets, the flow time of each product is:

Bread: 7,4 days

Milk 39,2 days

Butter 16,4 days

Eggs 45,8 days

Chocolate 25,9 days

The average flowtime now is 27.0, which is too high. I want to choose the product with the highest flow time and order 1 unit less.

What I want is something like this:
You have an order: T2; T3; T4; T5; T6.

IF " =AVERAGE(T2; T3; T4; T5; T6)" > 21, order - MAX(order) + (T one column to the left for that particular product)

In this case, the highest flow time is for eggs. What I thus want is to order 32 pallets instead of 33 for the eggs which makes the new order:
T2; T3; T4; S5; T6.

Now I want to check again if the order has a flow time > 21, and if it is, I need to do another iteration.

Can anybody help me on this problem? I have no experience with VBA or Macros, so it would be nice if this would be solvable within Excel.

Regards.

Image from comments:

[image: image of data]

Comment: Sounds somewhat like an optimization (minimization) problem that the Solver can handle.  It's really not clear from your example how the data is set up or if it is compatible with the Solver.  If you can post a picture, that would help.  Add a link to the post and I will edit it in since you don't have the rep.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I don't know how to add a link, but I have copied and pasted the data into a Google Drive link (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kq-faRAZQHyledqjNqwSY72dSsbIPfZLPNHvrrr6Dps/edit#gid=0). Maybe it is possible to copy and paste it into a Excel file and help me with the code? Thank you very much!

Comment: I have been trying to use the solver but I just can't seem to find how I can do it, especially since I have to know how much to order of each of the products.  And here I have the picture: snag.gy/jd6xS.jpg